# Clarity between functions in C

Tags: c, function, struct

I understand the concept of functions, really but I'd like to understand more of the differences between them. It seems like there are 4 variations of using functions in C:

1. Those that require parameters and do NOT return a value
2. Those that require parameters and do return a value
3. Those that do NOT require parameters and do return a value
4. Those that do NOT require parameters and do NOT return a value (I have used these mostly in BASH scripting

I understand what all of them do but just a bit confused. It mainly has to do with the first 3 (I get the last one as its simple).

When would a programmer use either of the first three functions? I have a couple here that use structures but just not sure why their are written the way they are:

```
    struct employee read_emp()
    {
        struct employee    x;

        printf("Please enter the address: ");
        scanf("%s", &x.address);

        return x;
    }


    print_emp(struct employee y)
    {
        printf("Address is %s\n", y.address);
    }
```

Then it is called like this:

```
    main()
    {
        struct employee    emp1, emp2;

        emp1 = read_emp();
        print_emp(emp1);
    }
```

So the `print_emp()` function uses as a parameter, another function which is the `read_emp()` function. This confuses me quite a bit. The first function read_amp() does not take any parameters but it was required to define a type before defining it as so: `struct employee read_emp()`. then a struct variable is initialized and it returns a value. Now whenever we call this function, a parameter is not needed, I understand that. What does come back from calling the function would be the result, which is whatever was entered from the keyboard. Got that.

However, the function below it does NOT take any type definition such as `struct employee` before `print_emp()`. Also no variables are initialized and no return value is needed. However, it takes a parameter as a structure variable declaration. why here and not in `read_emp()`?

The `read_emp()` function is an example of a function in the list I stated as number #3
The `print_emp()` function is an example of a function in the list I stated as number #1

Function from the list number #2 seems self-explanatory as well: Here is an example I understand:

```
float average(int n1, int n2, int n3)
{
   return (n1 + n2 + n3) / 3;
}
```

It's easy to understand this because it takes 3 parameters and returns a value. Thus when we call it in main(), it would look like this (assuming main has another input function or section where we read in 3 numbers for the user's keyboard:

```
average(num1, num2, num3);
```

I just don't get why `read_emp()` takes no parameters and returns a value, and `print_emp()` is the opposite and takes as parameter a declaration of a structure variable. Why wouldnt `read_emp()` do that too? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: As a side note, change the `3` in your `average` function to `3.0` so the result won't get rounded down.

Comment: Look up the standard library functions.  See how those are used to get a good feel about different ways functions are used.

Comment: thanks for all the comments guys. All were very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters are used to pass information *from* the part of the program that calls the function *to* the function. This will typically be the information that the function needs to do its job. Return values (whose type is declared before the function name) are used to pass information *from* the function *to* the part of the program that called the function; this will typically be the result that has been computed by the function.

Most functions both take parameters and have return values; these functions are very flexible because they can be used without requiring user interaction or showing anything to the user (but if you do want to feed them information from the user or show their result, you can read input before calling the function or write output after calling the function). Those that don't take parameters will either get their information from outside the program (by reading input from the keyboard or from a file) or from a global variable (or they might not need information at all because they do the same thing every time). Those that don't have a return value will send their result out of the program (by writing output to the screen or to a file) or store it in a global variable.

Comment: So what I am understanding is that those that do not take parameters will get their information from outside the program, in this case, from the print_emp() function correct? This is what seems to be indeed true. If so, that is a very good explanation of it. It makes more sense to me. And I do see printf never returns a value since it usually just outputs to a screen. But you're saying if it were to output to a file, then there also would not need the "return" part of the function, correct?

Comment: This helped me understand it quite a bit. read_emp() does not take any parameters because it will later be fed into the print_emp() function, which is how it gets its "information outside the program". Also im much more clear on understanding how print_emp did take a parameter (which is basically a structure variable) and read_emp() can be used as that. read_emp() itself is taking the place of 'y' in the struct employee parameter of print_emp().

Comment: @unixpipe: "those that do not take parameters will get their information from outside the program" is generally correct, although such functions may also get their information from global variables. However, `print_emp` is not such a function, but `read_emp` is. `print_emp` is similar to `printf`, in that their primary purpose is to take information from inside the program (via parameters) and present it to the user. `printf` actually does return the number of characters that were printed, but we usually don't care about that information and choose not to store it anywhere.

Comment: @unixpipe: ...and indeed, a function that outputs to a file might not need to return anything. However, it's not the function `read_emp` that gets passed into `print_emp` - it is the _result_ of `read_emp` that gets stored in `emp1` by using `=`, and afterwards, it is passed on to `print_emp` as a parameter. Note that the user doesn't see information that is passed via parameters (which is usually good); only `printf` has the effect of displaying its parameters.